# Our solutions meet the requirements industry security standards from different governing bodies around the world

Tags: grammar, terminology

Can you please read this sentence:

> Our solutions meet the **requirements industry security standards** from different governing bodies around the world.

Is there a mistake in "requirements industry security standards"?

Comment: Yes, it should have 'of' between 'requirements' and 'industry'

Comment: My friend insists that the original phrase is eligible in American English. Can anyone else confirm?

Comment: You might tell him that eligibility is not a characteristic of words in American English.  @BoldBen is right.

Comment: Maybe he thinks you wrote "required" instead of "requirements"?

Comment: Unless, of course, there's a Requirements Industry. I can tell you requirements gathering is almost an industry unto itself in the software space.

Comment: Without further context, the sentence makes sense - something about meeting security standards in the requirements industry, as set by international bodies that govern that industry. There's no guarantee that this was what the author intended, however.

Comment: Ah, the security standards of the requirements industry.  Such is the life of a proofreader.

Comment: As others have noted, "*requirements industry security standards*" makes sense only if there is an industry of requirements. Note also that *industry standards* are very different from standards imposed by "*governing bodies*" - so the entire sentence makes no sense on a different level.

Comment: @Lawrence I should have thought of that. I had a friend who was made redundant from a requirements factory when they introduced CNC machines, I miss those traditional hand-crafted requirements:-)

Comment: The only way I can put Humpty Dumpty back together is like this "Our solutions meet the requirements *pertaining to* industry security standards *enacted by* different governing bodies around the world." I have no Idea if that is what was meant.

Answer (score 1):

As you have written it:

> requirements industry security standards

is describing the security standards of the requirements industry.

This literally means that the requirement industry (the industry responsible for overseeing the process of acquiring and defining requirements) has standards for the security of these processes.

This is very unlikely - there is no such thing as the 'Requirement Industry' - it may be a process within a corporation, but is not outsource-able.

A more methodical read suggests that we are looking at the 'industry security standards', and the requirements that are needed to be passed in order to satisfy them.

I suggest:

> Our solutions meet the requirements of the industry security standards defined by governing bodies around the world.

(in my opinion 'different' can be dropped because this is implicit in 'around the world').

Answer (score 0):

Our solutions meet the requirements of industry security standards of different governing bodies around the world.

Alternately,

Our solutions meet the requirements prescribed by/ set by industry security standards of different governing bodies around the world.

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing your exact industry, I think it would be clearer to say:
Our solutions meet industry requirements for security standards established by governing bodies around the world.

Since there are definitely industry requirements, I'm hoping there is not also a requirements industry. Requirements industry requirements sound exhausting.

Answer (score 0):

> requirements industry security standards

Should be rephrased. There are several options:

- (the) Industry security standard requirements
- The requirements for industry security standards
- The industry standard requirements for security

I would have instinctively picked either the third or first option (in that order of preference), but they are all equally correct.